# Comparing the HKEY_USER and HKEY_CURRENT_USER

Tags: c#

Is any easy method to compare two registry keys ?

I want to compare user and current user keys in Windows Registry.

If the values changed, I want to pick out and correct with default value in HKEY_USER.Default.

Please Guide me..

Thank You.

Comment: First, I have to match the key name, then the values.. if they are not matched with the default value which is in the HKEY_USER\\.Default.

Answer (score 1):

In code? You can export the Key using the regedit tool and then use winmerge to compare the files.

Comment: I have to write C# code for comparing the keys. If the values are changed i have to correct it by the default value.